# How do I access elements of a yml file in opencv?

Tags: c++, c, opencv, matrix, yaml

I have a yml file which looks like this:

%YAML:1.0

```
X: !!opencv-matrix
    rows: 13
    cols: 40
    dt: f
    data: [ 166.000000, 162.666667, 159.333333, 
        156.000000, 152.666667, 149.333333, 146.000000, 
        142.333333, 138.666667, 135.000000, 131.333333,.... etc
```

How do I convert this file into matrix form and access its elements. I have to do some mathematics operations on this matrix. I have written the following code to read this file. What shall I do if I want to say subtract its 1st column from the second? Please help.

Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "cv.h"
#include "highgui.h"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char * const argv[])
{   
Mat X;
string XFile  = "newStorageFile.yml";
FileStorage fsDemoX(XFile , FileStorage::READ);
fsDemoX["X"] >> X;

cout << "Print the contents of X:" << endl;
cout << X << endl << endl;

fsDemoX.release();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: How exactly is this question related to YAML? Are you able to perform your operation when you don't have to read the matrix from a file? Or are there any errors when reading the file? Or is you question only about how to perform the operation with the matrix?

Comment: @sietschie: I have yml file, I want a way to access and manipulate matrix operation on this yml data. How do I go about further. I do not have any errors while reading the file.
Thanks
Hari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an OpenCV matrix stored in yml format.
You have all the documentation you need to load the matrix in the [persistency page](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/xml_yaml_persistence.html) of the documentation.

Then you can process your matrix either as an [array of coefficients](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html) or as a [matrix](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat) (in algebraic meaning).

As a side note, you do not need to call the `fsDemoX.release()` method, the destructor will be automatically called when reaching the end of the scope.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am a beginer in Opencv so can  u elaborate more on what is meant by "load the matrix in the persistency page of the documentation"?
Thanks
Hari